# Transposing the rows manually

Tags: kettle, pdi, pentaho-spoon

I'm using the denormaliser step, in Targetfieldname column of denormaliser step I want to include 8000 rows, it is not convenient to manually enter the 8000 rows. Can someone help me with some automation?

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you post your code?

Answer (score 0):

Look at the format of the `ktr` (kettle transformation) files. It is pure XML. You should be able to generate an XML with the fields you need.